# Add Item to HTML Select via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I want to be able to allow users to add their own options on an HTML select dropdown. I have most of the code written except for the part where it takes the value and create an "option" under the select menu.

*HTML*

```
<li id="add_1_parent">
    <div>
        <select width="100" class="add_select add_referral">
            <option value="">Incorporation</option>
            <option value="">Corporation</option>
            <option value="">Limited Liability Corporation</option>
            <option value="">Sole Proprietor</option>
        </select>
        <a href="#" id="add_1_child">Add</a>
    </div>    
</li>
```

*JS*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add_1_child').click(function() {
        $('#add_1_parent').append('<input id="add_1_foster_add" class="add_input" type="text" size="50" class="" value="" maxlength="255"/><a href="#" id="add_1_foster_child">Add</a>');
    });
    $('#add_1_foster').click(function() {
        // Add the value to the select HTML here..?
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HWRWv/

When you click the `"Add"` button, it needs to show a text box.

When you click the second add as defined by `"add_1_foster_child"` it needs to take the value out of the `input`, turn it into an `<option>` under the `select` menu.

What I don't know how to do is to grab the value from the `input` and put it into the `select` menu.

Comment: The question is.. How do I grab the value of the #add_1_foster_add when the user inputs something and add it to the option menu

Comment: When you post a question, please do as much as you can to make it useful to future readers. This includes things such as posting your code directly in the question, and describing exactly what you don't understand, or where you're stuck.

Comment: Usually for things like this you would normally have an "other" selection which would then have a text input appear. Is there any reason you want to add the items to the select menu?

Comment: @travis the customer wants it like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you're after :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add_1_child').on('click', function() {
        var html = '<div class="add_container"><input class="add_input" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255"/><a href="#" class="add_link">Add</a></div>';
        $('#add_1_parent').append(html);
    });

    $('#add_1_parent').on('click', '.add_link',function() {
        var option = $('<option value="">'+$(this).prev('.add_input').val()+'</option>');
        $('.add_select').append(option);
        $('.add_container').remove(); //removes the add input after submission, optional ?
    });
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HWRWv/4/)

Answer (score 4):

You can add items simply by using the `.append()` function and constructing a string of the desired HTML.  Let jQuery add it for you.

```
var option_value = 42;
var option_text = "Meaning to life the Universe and Everything";
$('#select_id').append('<option value="'+option_value+'">'+option_text+'</option>');
```

[As noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696460/add-item-to-html-select-via-jquery#comment15510999_11696480), you should definitely take some precautionary measures to prevent your users from adding entries that might compromise the layout of your site - for example if someone was to enter some actual HTML code. Thanks [@Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108893/jason) for that insight.

Comment: How do I grab the value of the #add_1_foster_add when the user inputs something?

Comment: remember to escape your values. maybe create the option element empty first, then set content text and value seperatly

Comment: You need to worry about escaping characters with that method, however.  If the user enters a value with a double quote it'll break.  You should use `.attr` to get around that.

Comment: That all depends on what type of element `#add_1_foster_add` is.  And if you want it as the value or the text.

Comment: your inputs should have name then you can do $('input[name=foobar]').value

Comment: @Lix can you work with the fiddle i posted and add a solution.. I don't know how to grab what the user inputted, that was my original question. I know how to append things.

Comment: @gre - you'll have to give each element a unique id value - at the moment you seem to be adding the same id value each time.  That's maybe why you are having problems extracting the value of `add_1_foster_add` - jQuery simply doesn't know which one you are talking about.

Comment: @greycode: See this is the problem. You didn't describe any of this in your question. No one knows what you know or don't know how to do, so people give up their time to explain things that you already know because you didn't take a little more time writing a better question.

Comment: It's better to post the code you are using and give the fiddle link as a reference.

Comment: Sorry @Lix . are you able to help me with the fiddle.

Comment: @Lix: Don't help him until he turns the question into something that can benefit the community. By refusing to do so, he's being selfish.

Comment: @greycode: It's not for me. I spend much time editing and answering and such to make StackOverflow more useful to beginners such as yourself. Your edit is very rude. You're lucky to have knowledgeable people here to help you. Don't push it.

Comment: @amnotiam I don't understand how it's a hard question to understand. I put everything in the fiddle. Everything needed to answer it. I have answers showing static variables. I need to grab the value and turn it into an option.

Comment: @greycode: You're not listening. As I said above, you need to make your question so that it is useful to future readers. This includes posting relevant code directly in the question. If/when your link breaks, the question loses meaning. Also, you should describe *exactly* what you don't understand. I don't know if you're lazy, or just not very bright. What I'm going to do is edit your question for you. After this, I expect that you'll behave in a polite manner. This sort if rudeness isn't well received here.